# How to organise and structure a custom Python library and multiple clients

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have written a few Python classes that exist in their own directory.

```
mylib/
  __init__.py
  a.py
  b.py
```

I've also written two clients that use the library:

1. Google AppEngine (in the `API` directory)
2. Python script providing a command line interface and flags (in the `CLI` directory).

My entire project directory is:

```
myproject/
  CLI/
     command_line_client.py
  API/
    app.yaml
    lib/
  mylib/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
```

I don't know if a canonical structure exists, but this seemed sensible because I can change the library once, and both the CLI and API will be updated.

However I'm unsure how this would actually work. Two problems specifically:

1. AppEngine requires libraries to exist in a `lib` subdirectory so they're deployed to AppEngine along with the app. How to I get `mylib` to the AppEngine lib subdirectory?
2. The `CLI` and `mylib` directory exist at the same level, so I'm unsure how Python imports work. How would my CLI Python script import the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a symbolic link for your `my_lib` folder inside `API/lib`. After that you can easily access `mylib` from your API service.

```
myproject$ ls -s ../mylib API/lib/
```

Comment: This looks good. QQ before accepting your Answer. How should these links be setup when someone clones a Git repo that requires symbolic links to build? Should the symbolic links be added to the repo, or should a shell script (e.g. `install.sh`) be added which generates any required symbolic links?